# Origin of the quote "Sadness is caused by intelligence"?

Tags: quote-source

In social media [(1)](https://twitter.com/liberadordemex/status/1093978039959064577)[(2)](https://www.facebook.com/Moodlivingph/posts/according-to-charles-bukowski-the-sadness-is-caused-by-intelligence-the-more-you/125566699097784/)[(3)](https://www.facebook.com/beastpublcations01/posts/according-to-charles-bukowski-sadness-is-caused-by-intelligence-the-more-you-und/118688403139027/), I have found:

> "Sadness is caused by intelligence, the more you understand certain things, the more you wish you didn't understand them." 
>   —  Charles Bukowski.

But yet I have no reliable source that can confirm me.
I will be grateful if you please tell me about the real quote-author and origin of this quote with proper resources.

Comment: Previously posted on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/537357)

Comment: @bobble I asked in both places because I thought it's more appropriate to ask here in Literature SE.